# Electron JS framework module issue (Cannot use import statement outside a module)

Tags: javascript, electron, frameworks

I am using Electron Js Version: ^28.  I have to use multiple overloading functions, So I decided to create a class (ComponentHamdler.js) so that My code can be more organized. By trying to import the class I am facing this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module. But still getting the same error:

here is my ComponentHandler.js:

```
class ComponentHandler{

    hideComponent(componentToHide){
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(componentToHide, component =>{
            component.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
                component.style.visibility = 'hidden'
            })
        })
    }
    showComponent(componentToShow){
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(componentToShow, component =>{
            component.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
                component.style.visibility = 'visible'
            })
        })
    }
    hideAndShowComponents(componentToShow, componentToHide){
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(componentToShow, component =>{
            component.style.visibility = 'visible'
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(componentToHide, component2 =>{
                component2.style.visibility = 'hidden'
            })
        })
    }
}
```

```
package.json :
{
  "name": "micro-to-to",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "clone microsoft to do",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {

    "start": "electron .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "to-do"
  ],
  "author": "Joe",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^28.2.1"
  }
}
```

I have tried to change "Type": in package.json to "module" Nothing happened.